# jquery mobile input file not updating img

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page with an img control on it.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageAvitarUpload">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2 style="font-weight: bold; font-size: .75em;" id="dlgHeader">Choose an Image file</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <input type="file" id="fileAvitar" accept="image/*" />

        <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
            <p>Preview</p>
            <img id="userImage" src="./images/UserPhoto.png" alt="User Photo" width="90" height="90" style="margin:0 auto; vertical-align:middle;" />
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="btnUploadAvitar" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am attempting to set up a preview when the input is changed by updating the src of the img control with the following code.

```
$("#fileAvitar").on("change", function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var _control = $("#userImage");
        reader.onload = function (e) { _control.attr('src', e.target.result); }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
})
```

My code runs fine but the img is never updated.  I am pulling what little hair I have left out because I know it must be something stupid.  A little more information is that this window is call as a dialog window when opened.

```
$("#btnAvitar").on("click", function () {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pageAvitarUpload', { role: "dialog" });
})
```

I thought that might be the problem but even when I took it out from being a dialog it still failed.  Please help as I have been looking at this for hours and am lost.  I have read every article I can find and have re-written this code 5 different ways but just can't get it to work.

TIA

Comment: Nothing from anyone?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle example or a link to an example page. What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: I figured it out and as I expected it was a loose nut between the chair and keyboard.  I had two img objects with the same name within my page.  Obviously a cut and paste issue.  Thank you Twisty for trying to help it is very appreciated and I hope that some day I can return the favor.